# Newline between delimiters in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I'm parsing a file, containing strings with nginx GET request bodies. And sometimes it contains line breaks between two parts of the same request, so I can't parse such request with `awk`.

I have two delimiters with `awk -F'delimeter1: |delimiter2'` and maybe I can somehow tell awk that there can be a line break between those delimiters, so it would process such two lines as one?

Thanks in advance.

Sample input (Java errors are random example):

```
[2017-12-04 20:53:07] [ERROR] [ID-XX] Get: sr=342x487&c64=(not set)&c1=Phones, MP3s, GPS&v=1&c33=427&d28=
Like
&je=0&s4d=4-b&c32=(not set)&ua=Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/32.0.2254/77.161; U; uk) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16&time=04/Dec/2017:20:52:02 +0200&qtype=get
com.test.app. java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
          at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:75)
          at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:359)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(FontDesignMetrics.java:350)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:302)
          at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
          at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:318)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateChildren(WrappedPlainView.java:297)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.insertUpdate(WrappedPlainView.java:463)
          at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1610)
          at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1869)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
          at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
          at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.read(DefaultEditorKit.java:273)
          at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1416)
  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
          at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
          ... 12 more
[2017-12-04 21:03:07] [ERROR] [ID-YY] Get: sr=342x487&c64=(not set)&c1=Phones, MP3s, GPS&v=1&em=Exception: Error: [$sc:ind] Aborting!&ua=Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/30.0.2254/77.161; U; ru) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16&time=04/Dec/2017:21:03:07 +0200&qtype=get
com.test.app. java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
          at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:75)
          at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:359)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(FontDesignMetrics.java:350)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:302)
          at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
          at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:318)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateChildren(WrappedPlainView.java:297)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.insertUpdate(WrappedPlainView.java:463)
          at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1610)
          at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1869)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
          at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
          at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.read(DefaultEditorKit.java:273)
          at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1416)
  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
          at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
          ... 12 more
[2017-12-04 19:40:02] [ERROR] [ID-ZZ] Get: el=search&dl=https://market.com/?dt=Market – Electronics Store | Web Store (Market.com)&id=104777577&a=770227875&t=pageview&ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; RNE-L21 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36&time=04/Dec/2017:19:39:04 +0200&qtype=get
com.test.app. java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
          at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:75)
          at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:359)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(FontDesignMetrics.java:350)
          at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:302)
          at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1113)
          at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:318)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateChildren(WrappedPlainView.java:297)
          at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.insertUpdate(WrappedPlainView.java:463)
          at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1610)
          at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1869)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
          at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
          at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
          at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.read(DefaultEditorKit.java:273)
          at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1416)
  Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
          at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
          ... 12 more
```

Desired output (print ID and body (in "") in one line and replace `&` with `_&_` ):

```
ID-XX "sr=342x487_&_c64=(not set)_&_c1=Phones, MP3s, GPS_&_v=1_&_c33=427_&_d28=Like_&_je=0_&_s4d=4-b_&_c32=(not set)_&_ua=Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/32.0.2254/77.161; U; uk) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16_&_time=04/Dec/2017:20:52:02 +0200_&_qtype=get"
ID-YY "sr=342x487_&_c64=(not set)_&_c1=Phones, MP3s, GPS_&_v=1_&_em=Exception: Error: [$sc:ind] Aborting!_&_ua=Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/30.0.2254/77.161; U; ru) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16_&_time=04/Dec/2017:21:03:07 +0200_&_qtype=get"
ID-ZZ "el=search_&_dl=https://example.market.com/?dt=Market – Electronics Store | Web Store (Market.com)_&_id=104777577_&_a=770227875_&_t=pageview_&_ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; RNE-L21 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36_&_time=04/Dec/2017:19:39:04 +0200_&_qtype=get"
```

There aren't much of those torn request body strings, most of them are in one line, as expected. Also, there're only GET request with an error, so search pattern shouldn't have to include `Get` (it's not necessary).

Comment: Thanks for your attention, @John1024. Hope my clarification is clear.

Comment: @cardinal-gray: There are _always_ three sets of lines like these?

Comment: @Inian nope, there's not much of those torn request bodies, most of them are in one line, as expected.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest there are only GET requests with an ERROR, so yeah

Comment: @cardinal-gray, single posted item would not be enough, post a few Get requests ... mixed single line and multiline

Comment: Would it be enough to have a preprocessor which joins any line which does not begin with a datestamp to the previous line?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest added some sample lines.

Comment: @tripleee don't think so, as this is parts of a Java log, so there's lots of rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'f{ if (/^\[/) { printf "\042\n"; f=0 } else printf("%s", $0) }
     / Get:/{ 
         f=1; gsub(/[\[\]]/, "", $4); id=$4; sub(/^.* Get: /, "");
         gsub("&", "_&_"); printf "%s \042%s",id,$0 
     }
     END{ if (f) printf "\042\n" }' file
```

- `/ Get:/` - on encountering *"Get request"* line

  - `f=1` - `f` is a marker indicating subordinate/inner processing
  - `id=$4` - capturing *ID* field (for ex. `ID-XX`)

The output:

```
ID-XX "sr=342x487_&_c64=(not set)_&_c1=Phones, MP3s, GPS_&_v=1_&_c33=427_&_d28=Like&je=0&s4d=4-b&c32=(not set)&ua=Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/32.0.2254/77.161; U; uk) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16&time=04/Dec/2017:20:52:02 +0200&qtype=get"
ID-YY "sr=342x487_&_c64=(not set)_&_c1=Phones, MP3s, GPS_&_v=1_&_em=Exception: Error: [$sc:ind] Aborting!_&_ua=Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/30.0.2254/77.161; U; ru) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16_&_time=04/Dec/2017:21:03:07 +0200_&_qtype=get"
ID-ZZ "el=search_&_dl=https://market.com/?dt=Market – Electronics Store | Web Store (Market.com)_&_id=104777577_&_a=770227875_&_t=pageview_&_ua=Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; RNE-L21 Build/HUAWEIRNE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.84 Mobile Safari/537.36_&_time=04/Dec/2017:19:39:04 +0200_&_qtype=get"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, man, it works nice, but, as I mentioned, it's Java log, so it contains lots of trashy output with classes names etc. after every of those error messages. Don't you know, how can I avoid them adding to the end of every `ID "request_body"` string? I'll add some example strings to the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to keep the line with ERROR and format them.

We don't know what are the delimiter.

It' strange you keep the get at the end of line.

You can try this sed

```
sed '
/.*ERROR] \[/!d                     # get the line with ERROR
s///                                # delete all from start to ID
:A
/=get$/!{N;bA}                      # if the line not end with =get; get one more
s/\([^]]*\)[^:]*: \(.*\)/\1 "\2"/   # remove Get: and add "
s/\n//g                             # remove \n
s/&/_&_/g                           # replace & by _&_
' infile
```